# Slurm parallelization with R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, slurm

I am trying to run an R script containing parallelization on Slurm but sum of the jobs fail with the following error:

```
slurm Error in serverSocket(port = port) : creation of server socket failed: port 11642 cannot be opened
```

The Rscript contains:

```
nproc <- 10
cl <- makeCluster(nproc)
registerDoParallel(cl)
...
stopCluster(cl)
```

I use the `sbatch` option with bash `for` loop to launch this R script 5 times on slurm as separate jobs with different parameters. Some of the jobs fail with the aforementioned error while some keep running.

Should the `nproc` in the Rscipt here and `ntasks` for slurm be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `ntasks` to more than 1 fails for me---the parallel package seems to get along better with `cpus-per-task`. My `#SBATCH` lines look like this:

```bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=51
```

With those lines, parallel recognizes 51 cores. My R file looks something like this:

```
library(parallel)
ncores <- detectCores() - 1 # to prevent 100% CPU usage
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG") # for RNG operations in parallel cores

results <- mclapply(some_sequence, function(x) some_analysis(x), mc.cores = ncores)
```

So, `ncores` is one less than `cpus-per-task`, but `ntasks` = 1.